# Arrays.sort returns a null array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

The Arrays.sort returns a null array in my java program.

When I execute my java program (pr13), on the command line, following is the output:

[image: Output]

Program Code:

```
import java.util.*;
class pr13{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    int[] ar = new int[10];
    int i, temp=ar[0];
    for(i=0; i<args.length; i++){
        ar[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    }
    Arrays.sort(ar);
    System.out.print("Sorted Array: ");
    for(i=0; i<args.length; i++){
        System.out.print(ar[i]+" ");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you run the program?

Comment: @Tunaki There is a big screenshot ;)

Comment: @KevinEsche Screenshots are blocked where I work :). That's why it's better to include the info in the post directly!

Comment: @Tunaki ah ok that explains your question quite well :)

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your array has 10 elements. You assign 4 values, but the others 6 are zeros (0). 
After you sort your array, you get 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, your values. And you print the first 4 zeros.

To avoid this, try to create array of required size

Comment: @user3382203 If this solved your problem, could you please mark this as answer ?